# how to get a count of orders for a given list of members and given intervals (equal to given_date +30day)

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder if anybody could give me an ideea on this query.
I have a list of memberID's and for each member I have a given set date (it represents a survey date) 
Is there an easy SQL query to get a count of orders created in the interval: given_date and +30 day?... basically have the members placed an order in the following 30 days after the survey.
I am getting this list on a monthly basis.
In my database there is a 'members m' table and an 'orders o' table; the 'orders' table has a 'o.created' as date field.

I can easily search on a individual member level, but the member list can be large, several hundreds of distinct members & given_dates.

[image: example]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also before asking question, it's good to learn how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sorry, i am new to this... i'll take your advise about asking questions.... so far i only checked to see if any simillar questions were asked before...but could not find something close enough...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
FROM members
WHERE given_date BETWEEN '2017-10-12' AND DATE_ADD('2017-10-12', INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: thanks Darshan...the thing is ...every memberID has a different associated given_date...if all would have the same base date, the suggestion above would probably have worked...

Comment: This solution would work fine for all the `given_date` values that fall in this interval. Member ids do not need to have same `given_date`.

Comment: I probably did not explained correctly...the database has the members and orders tables; members table will have the members.id, orders table will have the orders.created dates....the given_dates are not part of the database, these are external to the dataset. I am looking to extract the count of orders created in the interval 30 day from given_date....do you think it means i need to create a temporary table in the database (that contains the member.id, given_date pairing and then join from there?

Comment: 'members m' table structure: member.id; member.email; member.created...etc 'orders o' table structure: orders.id; orders.ref_no; orders.created etc....for a given set of membersID's we have associated 'given_dates' (when these members received a survey!!). These given_dates are not in the database.  I am interested to extract from database a count of orders for each member that were created between given_date and  +30day interval